# Issue with bottom dialog on Nexus devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, dialog

I created a dialog which shows from bottom to top and stays on the bottom of the screen. It is okay on custom aosp or LG stock roms, but on Nexus devices it shows strange artifacts on places where there is no dialog content.

[image: LG G2 AOSP]

[image: Nexus 6]

[image: Nexus 5X]

Some code:

```
public class BottomDialog extends DialogFragment implements MiniFragmentsCallback {

    public enum DialogType {SHIPPING, BILLING}

    private static final String DIALOG_TYPE = "dialog_type";

    private DialogType dialogType;
    @Setter
    private DataListener dataListener;

    public static BottomDialog newInstance(DialogType type, DataListener listener) {
        BottomDialog dialog = new BottomDialog();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable(DIALOG_TYPE, type);
        dialog.setArguments(b);
        dialog.setDataListener(listener);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            if (window != null) {
                window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wl = window.getAttributes();
        wl.x = 0;
        wl.y = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        wl.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        wl.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        return View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.bottom_dialog_layout, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, getDialogType()).commit();
    }
}
```

Style:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="56dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimationStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
</style>
```